# Nested spin-lock vs volatile check

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, atomic, compare-and-swap

I was about to write something about this, but maybe it is better to have a second opinion before appearing like a fool...

So the idea in the next piece of code (android's room package v2.4.1, RoomTrackingLiveData), is that the winner thread is kept alive, and is forced to check for contention that may have entered the process (coming from losing threads) while computing.
While fail CAS operations performed by these losing threads keep them out from entering and executing code, preventing repeating signals (mComputeFunction.call() OR postValue()).

```
    final Runnable mRefreshRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @WorkerThread
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mRegisteredObserver.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                mDatabase.getInvalidationTracker().addWeakObserver(mObserver);
            }
            boolean computed;
            do {
                computed = false;
                if (mComputing.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                    try {
                        T value = null;
                        while (mInvalid.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                            computed = true;
                            try {
                                value = mComputeFunction.call();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException("Exception while computing database"
                                        + " live data.", e);
                            }
                        }
                        if (computed) {
                            postValue(value);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        mComputing.set(false);
                    }
                }
            } while (computed && mInvalid.get());
        }
    };

    final Runnable mInvalidationRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @MainThread
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean isActive = hasActiveObservers();
            if (mInvalid.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                if (isActive) {
                    getQueryExecutor().execute(mRefreshRunnable);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

The most obvious thing here is that atomics are being used for everything they are not good at:

Identifying losers and ignoring winners (what reactive patterns need).

AND a happens once behavior, performed by the loser thread.

So this is completely counter intuitive to what atomics are able to achieve, since they are extremely good at defining winners, AND anything that requires a "happens once" becomes impossible to ensure state consistency (the last one is suitable to start a philosophical debate about concurrency, and I will definitely agree with any conclusion).

If atomics are used as: "Contention checkers" and "Contention blockers" then we can implement the exact principle with a volatile check of an atomic reference after a successful CAS.

And checking this volatile against the snapshot/witness during every other step of the process.

```
      private final AtomicInteger invalidationCount = new AtomicInteger();


      private final IntFunction<Runnable> invalidationRunnableFun = invalidationVersion -> (Runnable) () -> {
          if (invalidationVersion != invalidationCount.get()) return;
          try {
              T value = computeFunction.call();
              if (invalidationVersion != invalidationCount.get()) return; //In case computation takes too long...
              postValue(value);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      };
      getQueryExecutor().execute(invalidationRunnableFun.apply(invalidationCount.incrementAndGet()));
```

In this case, each thread is left with the individual responsibility of checking their position in the contention lane, if their position moved and is not at the front anymore, it means that a new thread entered the process, and they should stop further processing.

This alternative is so laughably simple that my first question is:

Why didn't they do it like this?

Maybe my solution has a flaw... but the thing about the first alternative (the nested spin-lock) is that it follows the idea that an atomic CAS operation cannot be verified a second time, and that a verification can only be achieved with a cmpxchg process.... which is... false.

It also follows the common (but wrong) believe that what you define after a successful CAS is the sacred word of GOD... as I've seen code seldom check for concurrency issues once they enter the if body.

```
            if (mInvalid.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                // Ummm... yes... mInvalid is still true...
                // Let's use a second atomicReference just in case...
            }
```

It also follows common code conventions that involve "double-<enter something>" in concurrency scenarios.

So only because the first code follows those ideas, is that I am inclined to believe that my solution is a valid and better alternative.

Even though there is an argument in favor of the "nested spin-lock" option, but does not hold up much:

The first alternative is "safer" precisely because it is SLOWER, so it has MORE time to identify contention at the end of the current of incoming threads.

BUT is not even 100% safe because of the "happens once" thing that is impossible to ensure.

There is also a behavior with the code, that, when it reaches the end of a **continuos flow** of incoming threads, 2 signals are dispatched one after the other, the second to last one, and then the last one.

But IF it is safer because it is slower, wouldn't that defeat the goal of using atomics, since their usage is supposed to be with the aim of being a better performance alternative in the first place?

Comment: What happens when the new action is scheduled right between `if (invalidationVersion != invalidationCount.get()) return;` and `T value = computeFunction.call();`? Then, you have overlapping computations. The logic of the first code snippet can be simplified though. Just by replacing the three `AtomicBoolean`s by a single `AtomicInteger` using three bits. Since there are several adjacent uses of the `AtomicBoolean`s (i.e. there’s no action with inter-thread semantics in-between), the single `AtomicInteger` allows to reduce the number of accesses.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Holger, I've made a list of all the possible scenarios of the first code, if by "overlapping" you mean 2 consecutive calls with the different result, that also happens in the first one (under a special case).
If you mean the same result computed twice, that happens also, it is just that the first computation is not dispatched the same computation is performed again and this time dispatched.
If you mean asynchronously, then the first code is still in the need to perform the second call AFTER the first dispatch was cancelled (the computation was still performed).

Comment: There is a definite advantage on the first code, and it is that it prevents the unnecessary creation of threads, which means the semaphore begins to work EVEN BEFORE the execution begins, that is what makes the task so complex, the problem is that it makes the task a lot more slow, so I believe we should also take into account what is the context of the code being used on, ...

Comment: if it will spawn thousands of calls then I believe the first one may be preferred, but if the memory is enough to handle multiple threads or if the calls would not be that much, then I believe my option is a valid one, maybe I am looking for too much excuses to use my code lol.

Comment: Depends on `getQueryExecutor()`. Normally, you would have a limit in executors. In fact, you could have a single threaded executor with a queue capacity of one, naturally preventing submitting a new job when there is a pending one. Besides that, I can’t tell for sure whether the first variant permits overlapping or not. That’s why I would use a single atomic integer for the state, to have far fewer state transitions and easy to understand code. That’s also the advantage of your variant, I can see immediately that concurrent calls of `computeFunction.call()` are possible.